# Floor Leveling/Finishing Options

Tags: flooring, joists, subfloor, self-leveling-concrete, leveling

I'm considering a few different options for leveling and refinishing an old floor and I'm looking for second opinions.

The floor is roughly 13'x28' on the top 3rd floor of a ~120 year old row house.  It has tng wood plank flooring with underlayment and two layers of old vinyl tiles on top.  Asbestos testing was negative.  Its a single room with a stair case coming up the middle.  The middle of the floor around the staircase is the low point of a 1.5" slope, with the most severe slope close to one long outer wall.  The floor was intentionally damaged during a recent re-insulation/rewiring.  The wall studs are irregularly place and mounted on top of the floor planks.

I'm considering 3-5 approaches, but I'm open to others:

1. Remove all old tiles with a pry bar.  Circular saw the floor planks along the 2nd joist from the walls.  Custom fit riser shims onto joists.  Reattach old floor planks on top of newly leveled joists.  Resurface with tng vinyl flooring.  This is a lot of dirty work, but seems the most proper and doesnt need a ton of material.  One danger though is that the wall studs are directly on the existing floor planks, oftentimes not directly over a joist, so disrupting the floor could easily disrupt the walls possibly causing serious structural problems.  If the 1st joist (with walls on top) is avoided, the worst of the slope will remain or need some other method of leveling.
2. Leave the existing flooring.  Lay on top one layer of 3/4" plywood sheets, a whole bunch of shims around the edges and a little floor leveling concrete for the gaps.  Then resurface with vinyl tiles probably? (I imagine tng wouldnt work since the floor would still be a little sloped)  This wont completely level the floor, but it would be a serious improvement.  It would require less work and entail less risk, but need more materials than option 1.  Its more weight on the floor, but only one layer shouldnt be too bad.  It feels hacky, but also a reasonable middle ground.  I could do the full 1.5" with 2 layers, but that seems like a lot of materials/weight...although it would allow for a tng surface rather than tiles or sheeting.  Using a bazillion shims along the edge of the plywood seems sloppy somehow.
3. Just slap another layer of new vinyl tiles or sheeting on top of the existing floor.  Its cheap, easy, safe and fast, but still sloped and not exactly pretty.  I'm sure a lot of ppl would pick this option as its not a high-traffic room and the other options have issues as well.
4. Do the same as option 1, but sister the joists and/or jack up the floor instead of shimming up the joists.  Some variation of this is often suggested, but it sounds like I'd have to jack up the central staircase for the entire house since its on the 3rd floor.  Positioning the joists might even require a crane due to the narrow staircase (2.5').  This seems overly drastic, way more risky and uses a ton of material/equipment.
5. Pour a bunch of floor leveling concrete.  Add tng vinyl flooring on top.  This is a ton of weight and materials.  Sounds pretty risky for a 3rd floor.

Okay, thanks for reading this far :)

Comment: why is it sloping ?

Comment: @Ruskes Likely foundation settling over the decades.  The 2nd floor is pretty similar.

Comment: Then you know the answer, rip out the existing floor and subfloor, repair the support structure

Comment: @Ruskes Repair the support structure in what way specifically?  Use risers, jacks, and/or sister joists?  What about supporting the walls while ripping up the old floor?

Comment: can not tell you what and how to repair without knowing the problem, the objective is to level the floor support beams

Comment: @Ruskes Alright, maybe a diagram would help.  I'll probably need another post though for that.  Thanks.

Comment: Levelling the floor is not always the best option. In a 100-year old house, _NOTHING_ is going to be level, plumb, or square, and as long as it has been stabilized against further subsidance it may be entirely reasonable to leave it that way and just adapt the furnishings when necessary. One corner of my dining room is probably 2" higher than the rest of the ground floor, and that's OK; it might affect the price I could get for it, but it also affected the price I paid... and I don't expect to ever sell it. It doesn't bother me, it doesn't damage anything, it can stay as it is.

Comment: Looking for second opinions is just as off topic as looking for first opinions. If you're looking the pros and cons of different approaches, well that's a different question and is on topic.

Comment: @keshlam Thats totally fair, I may end up with this approach.  Thanks.

Comment: @FreeMan Fair enough, I suppose in my mind I meant the same thing.  I'll using pros and cons phrasing next time for clarity.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You really need a plan view to visualize the area and some notes around the high / low spots.

I did 1.5"-2" and used the rip out the subfloor and add sleepers to the top of the joists to rough level then added 3/4" tng ply as the new subfloor.  you can always add blocking under walls as you go.

In your case maybe you just pull the tiles, add tapered sleepers 12" oc on the existing flooring and add a 5/8" tng plywood to the sleepers.  As long as your existing floor isn't squeaky you should be able to screw through the sleepers to the existing floor.  You can laminate areas with door skin at 1/8" or choose plywood at 1/2", 5/8" or 3/4" or rip sleepers to get the heights.  I tend to use a combination of techniques starting with sanding high spots and filling low spots.

You do have to factor in adjusting the stair riser heights for the new floor height.

Comment: Ahh, sleeper joists, that helps a lot, I didnt know that was a thing.  Looking up that phrase shows a very valid solution.  Thanks.

Comment: Also, blocking under the walls sounds like a reasonable solution when going for the 'rip up the floors' route.  It would make sense in a full gutting scenario, otherwise it seems like getting access would be rough.